# If $A$ is normal show that $A+A^*$ bijective implies $A$ is bijective

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose $A$ is a normal ($||Ax||=||A^*x||$ for all $x \in H$ ) bounded linear operator on a Hilbert space $H$. We want to show that if $A+A^*$ is a bijection then so is $A$.

A is injective is very easy since $kerA=kerA^*$ we have that  if $Ax=0$ then $x \in ker(A)\cap ker(A^*)$ so $x \in ker(A+A^*)$ so $x=0_H$.

I'm stuck on surjective. My hint is to use the open mapping theorem (so $A+A^*$ is open); but I can't see how this helps me at all.

I thought maybe I could prove $Im(A)$ was dense and closed but I can't relate either to $A+A^*$.

EDIT
In

Comment: @runway44 If $A^\ast A=AA^\ast$, then $\|Ax\|^2=\langle A^\ast Ax,x\rangle=\langle AA^\ast x,x\rangle=\|A^\ast x\|^2$. Moreover, your statement on kernels and ranges is not true. What is true is $(\mathrm{im}(A))^{\perp}=\ker A^\ast$ and the same with $A$ and $A^\ast$ exchanged.

Comment: @MaoWao I'm wrong on both counts! Thanks.

Comment: You want to prove that $A+A^*$ is open, but in order to use the open mapping theorem, you need to prove that $A+A^*$ is continuous, how is that true? (I know why, it's just a hint)

Comment: I think I know $A+A^*$ is open since it's bijective by hypothesis its certainly surjective and continuous since both $A$ and $A^*$ are?

Comment: Even knowing $A+A^*$ is open doesn't seem to help me get to $A$ is surjective?

Comment: Then it suffices to prove that $A$ is open.

Comment: ...should this be obvious? I feel like I'm missing something.  I think I can show $A$ is open [because $A(U)$ is merely a translate of $(A+A^*)(U)$] but $A$ open implies $A$ surjective is still mysterious to me.

Comment: If $A$ is open then $A(B(0,1))$ is open ($B(0,1)$ is the open unit ball). Therefore, there exists $r>0$ s.t. $B(0,r)\subset A(B(0,1))$, as $0=A(0)\in A(B(0,1))$, and therefore $A$ is surjective.

Comment: @Muselive $(A+A^\ast)(U)$ is in general not a translate of $A(U)$. By the same argument $0=A-A$ would be open whenever $A$ is, which is clearly not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $A$ and $A^\ast$ commute, we have
$$
\frac 1 4(A+A^\ast)^2-\frac 14(A-A^\ast)^2=A^\ast A.
$$
Since $A+A^\ast$ and $i(A-A^\ast)$ are self-adjoint operators, it follows that
\begin{align*}
\|A x\|^2&=\langle A^\ast Ax,x\rangle\\
&=\frac 1 4\langle (A+A^\ast)^2x,x\rangle-\frac 1 4\langle (A-A^\ast)^2x,x\rangle\\
&=\frac 1 4\|(A+A^\ast)x\|^2+\frac 1 4 \|i(A-A^\ast)x\|^2.
\end{align*}
By the open mapping theorem (or the bounded inverse theorem if youlike), there exists a constant $c>0$ such that $\|(A+A^\ast)x\|\geq c\|x\|$. Thus
$$
\|Ax\|\geq \frac{c}{2}\|x\|.
$$
Thus $A$ is a bijective operator from $H$ to $\operatorname{im}A$ with bounded inverse. In particular, $\operatorname{im}A$ is closed. Finally, if $y\perp\operatorname{im}A$, then
$$
0=\langle y,AA^\ast y\rangle=\|A^\ast y\|^2,
$$
hence $y\in \ker A^\ast=\{0\}$. Therefore, $\operatorname{im}A$ is also dense in $H$.

Here is a shorter answer that requires a little more technology: By the spectral theorem, the unital $C^\ast$-algebra generated by $A$ is $\ast$-isomorphic to $C(K)$ for some compact $K$, so this question boils down to the invertibility of $f\in C(K)$ under the assumption that $\operatorname{Re}f$ is invertible. Of course, an element of $C(K)$ is invertible if and only if it has no zero. Furthermore, the zeros of $f$ coincide with the zeros of $|f|$. Now all we have to do is to notice that
$$
|f|^2=(\operatorname{Re}f)^2+(\operatorname{Im}f)^2\geq (\operatorname{Re}f)^2>0.
$$

Comment: I don't see why the first part of your argument is necessary (or even why its there to be honest)?  Could you not just start from $A+A^*$ is bounded below?

Comment: Do you mean by "bounded below" that $\|(A+A^\ast)x\|\geq c\|x\|$?

Comment: In the end, I use $\|A x\|\geq \frac 1 2\|(A+A^\ast)x\|\geq \frac c 2\|x\|$. I am not sure which part you want to skip.

Comment: Hm I think you have that immediately from norm-equality of $Ax$ and $A^*x$ no? Since $2||Ax||=||Ax||+||A^*x||\geq ||A+A^*(x)||$ by triangle inequality?

Comment: Of course you can use that, too.

Comment: nevermind I isee it now

Answer (score -3):

For finite dimensions:
Isnt $A$ and $A^H$ simulataneously diagonalizable by unitary matrix cant u use that to prove this by simply saying $A+A^H = U (D+D^H) U^H$ and hence bijective iff $\lambda_i+conj(\lambda_i) \neq 0$ and hence $\lambda_i \neq 0$ and hence $A$ is bijective .

Comment: But in finite dimensions, bijectivity is equivalent to injectivity, which was already proof in the question.